# mySQL - Compare Table Rows

Tags: mysql, database, select

I'm just not too sure the proper way of doing this.  I basically have 2 tables.  Both table have the same structure.  Database1 (Current data average 20k rows), Database2 (accumlation of Data, can go over 1 mil row at any given time).

I want to compare both tables and give me result from Database1 that does NOT exist in the Database2 with a specific timestamp query.  What I have and tried yet query takes too long to search.

Tried:

```
select distinct player from Database1
where not exists (select player from Database2 where snap = 1340981695)

SELECT Database1.player FROM Database1
INNER JOIN Database2 ON Database1.player NOT IN (Database2.player) AND Database2.snap = 1340981695
GROUP BY Database1.player

select distinct Database1.player from Database1
left join Database2 on Database1.player not in (Database2.player)
and Database2.snap = 1340981695
```

I still cannot get my head wrapped around this.  Thanks for assistance.

Comment: please show your table structure and indexes

Comment: Both table has id,player,castle,xaxis,yaxis,snap and id being the primary key. No data are ever the same, always changing (added from Database1 into Database2 (copied from Database1 and always accumlate) when new data is produced and put in Database1.

Comment: There's not really going to be a fast way to do this. Placing an index on `player` and on `snap` should help as would joining by `id` (assuming they match in the tables). You might be better off dumping all the data flat files and writing a program to parse it to find the difference (grep would probably do this very quickly). Once you do that you should rethink your database design. MySQL does fine with 1M+ row tables. Why the need for 2?

Comment: basically reason for 2 tables is the current data in one and the dumps of all old data into another, so everytime I have a new data, those old data will be moved to database2 while new data goes to database1 for history storage purpose (non-essential).  Basically just trying to compare 2 tables to find out who is the "new user" that doesn't exist in the old database based on timestamp.  Hope that's clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three approaches.  In approximate order of [performance](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/), from best to worst:

1. Use an outer join:

   ```
   SELECT Database1.*
   FROM   Database1
     LEFT JOIN Database2
            ON Database1.id = Database2.id AND Database2.snap = 1340981695
   WHERE  Database2.id IS NULL
   ```
2. Use `IN`:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   Database1
   WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Database2 WHERE snap = 1340981695)
   ```
3. Use `EXISTS`:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   Database1
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM   Database2
            WHERE id = Database1.id AND snap = 1340981695
          )
   ```

Comment: Nested queries are the worst to think of. I don't think that one could get any performance out of them in any case. It's better not to use them.

Comment: Suggest you read @Quassnoi's blog article to which I linked; the second approach above has similar performance to the outer join.

Comment: That article assumes some special cases like index on particular columns. What I propose is that it is generally a bad idea to encourage people to write nested queries when you can easily do without them.

Comment: Nested queries have a valuable place in databasing.  Otherwise they wouldn't be supported.  For this circumstance eggyal provided great information for the question