# How can I compare if 2 tables have the same data?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, subquery

If I have 2 tables and want to find if they have the same data, what is the most straightforward way to do it in `MySQL`?
I have read about doing a correlated subquery and `UNION ALL` but this query is about 2 pages (!) and can not really follow what it is doing. There must be an easier way.
Even if it is e.g. make `MySQL` copy the table data to files and do a `vimdiff` (I am not sure that this is even possible -is it?- just thinking out loud).

**UPDATE**
I am interested only in the table data and not structure. This is to clarify due to an ambiguous comment I made

Comment: possible duplicate of [mySQL - Compare Table Rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279108/mysql-compare-table-rows)

Comment: How large are the tables? If they are small enough, you might dump them and compare the dump files (with `diff`) - assuming some key is indexing (and sorting) them suitably... Otherwise, show the schema of the database, or at least of the tables...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:They are big.But even if they were small I don't know how to do what you suggest.Would be interesting to me if you post it as part of an answer.I'll upvote

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:Why does the schema matter for this?Isn't there a specific MySQL solution for my problem?

Comment: @RobW:I am not interested in finding rows with different values.I want to know if table A and table B are exactly the same

Comment: Why would a query of just data from a table be two pages?

Comment: consider editing the question - if you want to know if the STRUCTURE of the tables is the same or the DATA in the tables is the same. - unclear.

Comment: Does your table has any unique index/constraint??

Comment: @Gratzy:I don't know.I found it in a cookbook and it is over 2 pages using correlated subquery and join

Comment: @Randy:It says in the title. Same data

Comment: yes but then you say in a comment: I am not interested in finding rows with different values.I want to know if table A and table B are exactly the same

Comment: @user2407394:Hmmm,I think so, but not 100% sure since I don't have currently access to the table

Comment: What's the reason for comparing (as in, what will you do if the tables don't match)? Was just thinking ahead..

Comment: @Randy:Ok.I meant contain the same data. I will update the OP since my comment seems contradictory

Comment: Having unique will simplify the solution to great extent..!!

Comment: @RobW:I am testing some code that updates the table.I am planning to compare the data to see if the new code updates the table correctly.If the code is correct the 2 tables should have the same data

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to tell whether the tables are identical or not as efficiently as possible, use this query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM (
   SELECT * FROM table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM table2
) t
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
HAVING count(*) = 1
LIMIT 1
```

- List all the columns in `GROUP BY` to compare the entire table.
- If the result is an empty set, the two tables are identical.

If you want to see the differences, use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT 'table1' tname, col1, col2, col3 FROM table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'table2' tname, col1, col2, col3 FROM table2
) t
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
HAVING count(*) = 1
```

- List the same columns in the inner `SELECT` as in the `GROUP BY`, plus a column to distinguish the two tables.

Comment: +1.But if they are not identical, I wouldn't be able to see the difference.

Comment: @Cratylus I updated my answer, I added a variation of the query for viewing the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out there, you could emulate a full outer join and then return the rows where just the right or the left side is null.

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
AND ...
WHERE t2.id is null
UNION
select t2.* 
from table2 t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1
ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
AND t2.col2 = t1.col2
AND ...
WHERE t1.id is null
```

With the FULL OUTER JOIN you can show all rows where the other row is not available in the other table.

Comment: +1.Why didn't you do a right join and reverted the order in the second part of the query?

Comment: No reason, I just lean towards left joins.m

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:

```
SELECT c1 = cjoin AND c2 = cjoin equiv
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) c1 FROM Table1) t1,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) c2 FROM Table2) t2,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) cjoin
      FROM Table1 t1
      JOIN Table2 t2
      ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2 AND t1.col3 = t2.col3 ...) tjoin
```

Assuming the tables have a unique key, this will return `equiv = 1` if the tables are equal. It doesn't show the differences, it's just a binary test.

Comment: I don't understand this.Why `SELECT COUNT`?

Comment: The third subquery finds the rows in the two tables that are identical. But if there are extra rows in either table, they won't be noticed. So I count the number of rows in each table, and if this is equal to the number of equal rows, it means there are no extra rows.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading SQL Cookbook from A.Molinaro, when I came across a solution.
It is based on to tables 
    **emp(empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,sal,comm,deptno)** 
and a view 
    **V** 
which has the same columns but different rows. The columns **mgr** and **comm** might be **NULL**, other columns not.
The solution in the book is very long and it does not show all differences, although this was the stated problem in 3.7.
I made up my solution which is shorter and shows all differences (means all rows which have different counts in the two tables).

```
select * from
# those which are contained in the (distinct) union of (col1,col2,...,coln, count) of both tables:
( select empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,comm,deptno, count(*) cnt from emp group by empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,comm,deptno
   union
  select empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,comm,deptno, count(*) cnt from V group by empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,comm,deptno
) as unionOfBoth
where (empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,comm,deptno,cnt)
not in
# those which are contained in the intersection of both tables with the equal number of counts:
( select e.empno,e.ename,e.job,e.mgr,e.hiredate,e.comm,e.deptno,e.cnt
  from
  (select empno, ename,job,mgr,hiredate,comm,deptno, count(*) cnt from emp group by empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,comm,deptno) e,
  (select empno, ename,job,mgr,hiredate,comm,deptno, count(*) cnt from V group by empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,comm,deptno) v
  where 
   e.empno = v.empno 
   and e.ename = v.ename
   and e.job = v.job
   and ifnull(e.mgr,0) = ifnull(v.mgr,0)
   and e.hiredate = v.mgr
   and e.deptno = v.deptno
   and ifnull(e.comm,0) = ifnull(v.comm,0)
   and e.cnt = v.cnt
);
```

Basically you count the distinct rows in both tables and do a union (not union all) to get the tmp.table **unionBoth**. Then you remove those rows, which both tables have in common.
Here two rows r1 from table t1 and r2 from table t2 are considered the same, if 
    **(r1,count of r1 in t1) = (r2, count of r2 in t2)**, which is equivalent to **r1=r2** (on all columns) **and** **(count of r1 in t1) = (count of r2 in t2)**.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are small enough, you can export both tables as csv files and then copy one of the tables and paste them side-by-side with the other table. You can just go row by row and see if the outputs are the same that way.

Comment: I think the OP wants to do this programmatically.